# django admin site override the change_list.html

Tags: django

is their any possible to override the change_list.html?
[image]

i just want to add another table/listview,

models.py

```
class StudentsEnrollmentRecord(models.Model):
    Student_Users = models.ForeignKey(StudentProfile, related_name='students', on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True)
    School_Year = models.ForeignKey(SchoolYear, related_name='+', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    Courses = models.ForeignKey(Course, related_name='+', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    Section = models.ForeignKey(Section, related_name='+', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True,blank=True)
```

admin.py

```
class StudentsEnrollmentRecordAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    #inlines = [InLineSubject]
    list_display = ('lrn', 'Student_Users', 'Education_Levels', 'Courses', 'Section', 'Payment_Type', 'Discount_Type' ,'School_Year')
    #list_select_related = ('Student_Users')
    ordering = ('Education_Levels','Student_Users__lrn')
    list_filter = ('Student_Users','Education_Levels','Section','Payment_Type')


    def lrn(self, obj):
        return  obj.Student_Users.lrn
```

**Update example**
[image]

Comment: What do you mean add another table? For another model? Or for the same model?

Comment: add another table for the another model sir,

Comment: That's not possible. The django admin site handles one model at a time in the list view.

Comment: how to do that sir? can you provide me an example?

Comment: I provide an example sir of what I mean, see my update example

Comment: I said what you want is **not possible** in the django admin site.

Comment: you said, its not possible

Answer (score 1):

You have to create a directory into your projects path like so: myproject/templates/admin (if this is your specified template setting in the DIRS template options within settings.py) and create a new file called change_list.html in this directory. Django will then use this instead of the default one.

Furthermore you can then use this new change_list.html template to expand on/work with.

For further reference on overriding & replacing default admin & registration templates also see: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/admin/ -> search for "Overriding admin templates"

Comment: any specific answer sir? do I have to change or add my admin.py code?

Comment: @justinorcullo what do you mean specific? Your question isn't specific (it just asks how to modify change_list.html, it doesn't say anything about what you want to change) and the answer is exactly telling how to do that. No you don't have to modify admin.py if all you want is change change_list.html